# PHP - Showing the next row from database on each pageload

Tags: php, sql

I need to be able to show next **quote** from database on each page load. How can I accomplish this?

The only solution I can think of would be:

```
1. SELECT counter FROM certain_table
2. SELECT COUNT(*) as num_of_quotes FROM quotes
3. counter = (counter + 1) % num_of_quotes;
4. SELECT * FROM quotes LIMIT counter, 1
5. Show quote
6. UPDATE certain_table SET counter = {counter}
```

But this means that 4 SQL queries will be done each time to show a quote. Any way to do it more **efficiently**?

P.S. It will be coded in PHP and page will be available for use on external pages, through a JS file.

Comment: use session to store page load count, and depend on that call sql to show new quote. Hope that will work

Comment: @demochanico did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column in your quotes table, and call it `view_counter`. This will contain the number of times each quote has been shown to the user.

This example presumes the table structure as follows:

```
quotes(id, quote, view_counter)
```

Here's the query:

```
select id, quote
from quotes
order by view_counter asc
limit 1
```

Pretty simple, right? Now, before rendering the page, run the following query:

```
update quotes set view_counter = 1+ view_counter where id = :quote_id
```

where `:quote_id` is the value of the query id you downloaded.

Two queries! not bad. But what if we have a race condition, and by chance two different users request a query at the same time? You have two choices:

1. Don't care (which I endorse) because nobody will lose a sweat if somebody else has read the same quote as him, the other side of the world.
2. Lock tables. If you want to use this route, run this query before the 2 I said: `LOCK TABLES quote WRITE` and this one as last query `UNLOCK TABLES`

I vote for option 1.

Comment: A decent solution! Yeah, option 1 will do the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are storing your quotes with a unique ID, you could do something like this

next quote:

```
SELECT * FROM `quotes` WHERE `id` > $currentID ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1 ;
```

for previous quote

```
SELECT * FROM `quotes` WHERE `id` < $currentID ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1 ;
```

basically you will be looking for the next and previous ID in your database. and comparing it to the one you are on right now. This will display the quotes you want

Comment: You should add an `ORDER BY id ASC` (or `DESC` for previous).

Comment: The next quote needs to be loaded at the time of page load (A random user loads the page and gets the next quote from the list). So I don't have the currentID and hence can't get the next ID.

Comment: so everytime the page is loaded show the next quote? in that case, use $_SESSION with id of 1, and slow2 increment thru (replace $currentID with the session)

Comment: @user2035819, the user does not have a "current ID", also, there may be different users so SESSION can't be used.

Comment: Usage of SESSION sounds good, but are sessions stored for each user, or are they global?

Comment: @demechanico they're stored for each user

Comment: Also, if the user "goes away" and then comes back, he'll get to see the first query again. This isn't a good approach because your website will always show only the first quotes over and over again.

Comment: yes then you will have to store it a user DB or cookie. use a user DB if user is a registered user, and cookie if he is not

Comment: @stt-lcu I see. Actually, the original coder used Cookies, which didn't quite do what I wanted it to as well, working just as you said.